# C++ Object definition vs initiation

Tags: c++, object

I everyone,
I am new with C++ and I don't understand when a object is created when its definition is inside a library. For example the next code in Object1.h:

```
class Object1 {
public:
    Object1(int cause);
    void start();
    void f2( string msg );
    void f3( uint32_t ts );
    bool f4();

private:
    void reset();
    void loop();

    static Object1 *_self;
    uint8_t _offset;
    int _wdReset;
    Timers _timers;
    Tmr *_resetTimer;

    SDFileSystem _fs;
};
```

In this example this class "Object 1" has a declaration of object Timers called _timers, then when I create an instance of Object1 an instance of Timers is also created for these Object 1 or is only a definition and is created else where? When is called the constructor for the object Timers?

I ask because for example in the method start of Object1 (file Object1.cpp) the line `_section[_offset++] = ( Section * ) &_timers;` is used (Timers inherit from Section), then if I understand well _timers must be already created in order to get his address.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Time for you to do some reading on C++ methinks. In short, indeed an instance of `Timers` is constructed just before the constructor body of `Object` is ran.

Comment: Whatever source you're using to learn C++ should have something to say about [how constructors work](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor). In particular, member variables are initialized before the body of the constructor is entered, meaning that `_timers` is initialized when an instance of `Object1` is.

Comment: You haven't shown where the line `_section[_offset++] = ( Section * ) &_timers;` comes into play. `_section` isn't a member variable in `Object1`. My answer answers your direct question - but in order to give any advice or information on top of that I would need to see that code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I create an instance of Object1 an instance of Timers is also created for these Object 1 or ...

Yes.

> ... is only a definition and is created else where? When is called the constructor for the object Timers?

You got it right the first time. The `Timers` instance `_timers` is created when an `Object1` is created.

When you enter the body of the `Object1` constructor, all member variables have been created:

```
Object1::Object1(int cause) /*here _timers is instantiated*/{    
}
```

Comment: Rollback if you think I'm being too pedantic, but methinks the edit is more accurate.

Comment: @Bathsheba No, that's perfect, thanks. I was going to get on with the initialization list, but I think I'll leave it at this for now.

Comment: Have an upvote - this answer is correct, if a little laconic for the question; which is possibly too broad.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks :) I'm trying to figure out if I can give some advice regarding `_section[_offset++] = ( Section * ) &_timers;` now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys, It was like I was thinking but I needed to be sure. There are a lot of curses and tutorials but Is difficult to find exact responses.